# Multiple INNER JOINS MySQL w/ .csv OUTFILE Statement And ORs and ANDs Query - Returning Database Name Error

Tags: mysql

I've been toying with this SQL for a few hours now, and running into an issue where MySQL CLI is returning "mydatabasename.a table does not exist" - I verified I am in fact using the correct database by previous tests and the USE statement. My guess is the query is faulty, but I am having a really tough time getting away from this error. Thanks for any ideas.

```
SELECT a.tabl1, b.tabl2, c.tabl3
INTO OUTFILE 'H:/output/output.csv' 
fields TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM a, b, c   
INNER JOIN a.tabl1 ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN b.tabl2 ON b.id = c.id
WHERE 
       (

   b.case_txt = 'case1' OR   
   b.case_txt = 'case2' OR
   b.case_txt = 'case3' OR
   )

AND 
c.address != ''
AND 
c.state = 'OR' 
AND 
date LIKE '%02/01/13%';
```

Comment: Are the tables named "a" or "tabl1"?

Comment: Is `a` really your table name? I don't see where you have supplied an table name alias, so if this isn't the real table name you will have this problem.  Also your JOIN syntax is odd.  Try `FROM a INNER JOIN b ON  a.id = b.id INNER JOIN c on b.id = c.id`. I am confused here as you specify this `INNER JOIN a.tabl1` You can't specify a column name as the join target, column names can only be used in `ON` condition.

Comment: Hi SQLDBA, tabl1, tabl2. tabl3 are the table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ths what you are looking to do?

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
INTO OUTFILE 'H:/output/output.csv' 
fields TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM tabl1 a 
INNER JOIN tabl2 b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN tabl3 c ON b.id = c.id
WHERE 
   (
   b.case_txt = 'case1' OR   
   b.case_txt = 'case2' OR
   b.case_txt = 'case3'
   )
```

...etc.

Comment: I figured this out a few minutes ago, and your code matches what I came up with. Thanks for the guidance and suggestions. This does work.

Comment: I should add a note that I needed to add headers to the .csv file and had to modify this some: SELECT 'id', 'case_text' UNION 
SELECT a.id, b.case_text INTO...

Comment: @OldWest - This code won't work. See the needless `OR` at the end. Results in an error.

Comment: Right, the code that I came up with didn't have the extra OR, appears to be a simple error from SQLDBA. I removed the OR.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
FROM a, b, c                        -- cartesian product of these three tables joined with   
INNER JOIN a.tabl1 ON a.id = b.id   -- nonexisting tables a.tabl1 (table tabl1 in db a)
INNER JOIN b.tabl2 ON b.id = c.id   -- and tabl2 in database b
```

you want to use

```
FROM a  
INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN c ON b.id = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join 3 tables called `tabl1` (alias `a`), `tabl2` (alias `b`) and `tabl3` (alias `c`) and select all resulting fields into a .csv file, this is how it works:

```
SELECT *
    INTO OUTFILE 'H:/output/output.csv' 
    fields TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    FROM tabl1 AS a
    INNER JOIN tabl2 AS b
    ON a.id = b.id
    INNER JOIN tabl3 AS c
    ON b.id = c.id
    WHERE (
        b.case_txt = 'case1' OR   
        b.case_txt = 'case2' OR
        b.case_txt = 'case3'
   )
   AND c.address != ''
   AND c.state = 'OR' 
   AND date LIKE '%02/01/13%';
```

**[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)**

I tested the code locally and it works like a charme.